# How to save and sort coordinates (of points) in scheme?

Tags: scheme, racket

I want to save coordinates of points (X,Y) in a list. Also I want to sort the list by X or Y value every time I add points in that list.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this in Scheme. In this answer I'll use [PLT Scheme](http://www.plt-scheme.org/) (as your tag suggested). I'll give links to the PLT Scheme [documentation](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/) where you can read more about these things.

First of all we can [define a point structure](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/define-struct.html#(form._((lib._scheme/base..ss)._define-struct))).

```
 (define-struct point (x y) #:transparent)
```

This simple definition will automatically create many useful function which we can use when working with our points

- `(make-point 3 4)` will create a new point with coordinates (3,4)
- `(point-x <some-point>)` returns the x coordinate, ex. `(point-x (make-point 3 4))` evaluates to `3`

To [sort](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/pairs.html#(def._((lib._scheme/base..ss)._sort))) a list of points by their y coordinates:

```
(define (sort-by-y lst)
  (sort lst
        <
        #:key point-y))
```

If you want to keep the list sorted when you `insert` a new point you can do something like

```
(define (insert x xs #:predicate (p <) #:key (k (lambda (x) x)))
   (if (null? xs)
       (list x)
       (let ((y (car xs)))
         (if (p (k x) (k y))
             (cons x xs)
             (cons y (insert x 
                             (cdr xs) 
                             #:predicate p 
                             #:key k))))))
```

The `insert` function takes two optional arguments:

- a predicate function, which can be used to keep the list sorted according to different orderings (defaults to <)
- a key function which can be used to extract an element from some structure (defaults to the identity function)

This function can be used like this:

```
> (insert 3 (list 1 2 4 5 6))
(1 2 3 4 5 6)

> (insert (make-point 3 5) plist #:key point-y)
(#(struct:point 2 1) 
 #(struct:point 9 2) 
 #(struct:point 1 3) 
 #(struct:point 3 5) 
 #(struct:point 6 6))

> (insert (make-point 3 5) (reverse plist) #:predicate > #:key point-y)
(#(struct:point 6 6) 
 #(struct:point 3 5) 
 #(struct:point 1 3) 
 #(struct:point 9 2) 
 #(struct:point 2 1))
```

where `plist` is a sorted list of points.

Comment: Fabulous! Thanks a lot Jonas. Great explanation!

I am very new in plt-scheme. An I think (personally) the scheme books or docs are written in such a way that you have to start from the beginning, and you can not fly randomly as per your requirement. 

It will be better if you can guide to doc links. That will help me to be on track and try the doc before asking next question :)

Comment: Oops, I changed my answer quite a bit before I read your comment. Should I roll back to my original answer?

Comment: Nop, It's ok...I already have tried those codes. So those are here already :)

I thought it could be done in single line with "cons". Like sort while adding points each time...Like in the following line- "  (cond 
     [(mouse=? "button-down" ke) 
      (cons (list x y) w)] 
     [else w])) " 
So, can it be done after cons method like "sort (w x)" or something?